# How to track mouse clicked between linestring openlayer 6

Tags: reactjs, openlayers-6

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0WEx.png)

I have two coordinates start point and end point. I have added coordinates in linestring. When user click between anywhere in line my line coordinates should be return. Please review my code:

import LineString from 'ol/geom/LineString';

const line = new LineString([[lat1, lon1],[lat2, lon2]]);
console.log(line.intersectsCoordinate(map.getEventCoordinate(evt)));

It always return false. I want to know user click on exact line and it should return true/false.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the SO community. Please add correct tags, there is nothing related to `reactjs` in your example, but on the other hand it is missing the most important `javascript` tag. 
Also, please use [correct code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and have a look on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This shows little effort in trying to explain your problem, and will most likely get no answers.

Answer (score 0):

A click is only accurate to one pixel.  Also a linestring must be specified with Lon Lat coordinates (and transformed to the view projection if that is not EPSG:4326).   So the line could intersect anywhere in the extent of the pixel clicked.  That can be obtained by buffering the pixel center coordinate by half the resolution (which is projection units per pixel) in each direction.

```
import {boundingExtent, buffer} from 'ol/extent';

const line = new LineString([[lon1, lat1],[lon2, lat2]]);

console.log(line.intersectsExtent(buffer(boundingExtent([map.getEventCoordinate(evt)]), map.getView().getResolution() / 2 )));
```